# NHibernate and Sybase Case Statement null check

Tags: asp.net

I have table "mytable" where value of column "myValue" is null.

I have application where NHibernate calls Sybase Stored procedure.
In procedure,I have Case Statement where I check for null for a value.

Select Case myValue
   when null then
                0
    else
                1
   End as newValue
from mytable

When I execute this procedure in database tool, I get output as 0.
When I run my application, NHibernate executes this procedure and gives output of 1.

Now, when I change my Case Statement in stored procedure to 
Select Case 
   when myValue is null then
                0
    else
                1
   End as newValue
from mytable

Now, When I run my application, Nhibernate executes this procedure and gives output of 0.
It looks like changing SQL in stored procedure does matter to NHibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out, it was not NHibernate at all..

Our (new-ish) DB Driver didn't support "case null:",  "@var != null" or "@var = null" we had to use "@var is not null", "@var is null", or prepend our sql with  'SET ANSINULL OFF"